Face-based discrete directional derivative on triangular mesh
For a scalar function $f$ defined on the faces of a triangulated surface $M$, and a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ on its tangent space, is there a built-in or simple way to get the derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\mathbf{F}$ ?
To exemplify, let's take a sphere, the function $f=x y z ^2$, and the field $\mathbf{F}=\cos\theta\sin\varphi\:\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}+\sin\theta\cos\varphi\:\boldsymbol{\hat{\varphi}}$ (we write initially the field in spherical coordinates just to make sure it lies on the sphere, but generically it is given as an input in 3d cartesian basis. The mesh might also be irregular).
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {2 -> 1}]; 
centroids = AnnotationValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]; 
function = Table[x*y*z^2 /. {x -> centroids[[i,1]], y -> centroids[[i,2]], z -> centroids[[i,3]]}, {i, 1, Length[centroids]}]; 
field = TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {0, Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[CurlyPhi]]}, {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]} -> {x, y, z}]; 
fieldFace = Normalize /@ Table[field /. {x -> centroids[[i,1]], y -> centroids[[i,2]], z -> centroids[[i,3]]}, {i, 1, Length[centroids]}]; 


In general tho we don't have analytical expressions for $f$ or $\mathbf{F}$ but just the numerical lists with the order corresponding to the face order of the triangular mesh.

To clarify: in your example, the derivative of  in the direction of  is well defined even if  you do not consider the triangulated surface. How do you want to use triangulation data?  What is the relation between the vector field F and the surface M?

@A.Kato Thank you. The field is arbitrary however it is on the surface, meaning it is defined on its tangent space (I'm not sure how to properly define this for a discrete surface but I guess there should be a standard way to). The first question I don't get it.; M is an arbitrary triangle mesh.
